Circumradius of the intersection of two regular simplexes
For $n \geq 2$, let $\Delta^n$ be a regular $n$-dimensional simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin $0$ and inscribed in the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Let $v_0,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ be the vertices of $\Delta^n$.
Let $-\Delta^n$ be the symmetric of $\Delta^n$ with respect to the origin whose vertices are $-v_0,\dots,-v_n$ and $\Pi^n = \Delta^n \cap -\Delta^n$.
What is the circumradius $R_n$ of $\Pi^n$ ? Does this polytopes have a name ?
I've already computed $\Pi^2$ (which is a regular hexagon whose circumradius is $R_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ and $\Pi^3$ (which is a regular  octahedron whose circumradius is $R_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ but I don't know how to do it for higher dimensions.
I am interested if anyone has references on this subject, I skimmed through 'Regular Polytopes' by Coxeter but didn't find any answers there.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the lookup. I edited the post for this young newbie of our forum.

The intersection kernels of regular bi-simplex compounds are well-known for sure.
The $n$-dimensional intersection kernel of $x3o..o3o3o3o..o3o$ ($n$ nodes, the simplex) and $o3o..o3o3o3o..o3x$ ($n$ nodes, the dual simplex) is $o3o..o3x3x3o..o3o$ ($n$ nodes, the mid-truncated simplex), to be scaled down by a factor $n+1$, whenever $n$ is even.
The $n$-dimensional intersection kernel of $x3o..o3o3o..o3o$ ($n$ nodes, the simplex) and $o3o..o3o3o..o3x$ ($n$ nodes, the dual simplex) is $o3o..o3u3o..o3o$ ($n$ nodes, the mid-rectified simplex), to be scaled down by a factor $n+1$, whenever $n$ is odd.
(Throughout $x$ denotes unit edges and $u$ edges of twice these lengths.)
Thus within 2D you indeed obtain the hexagon, within 3D the octahedron, in 4D the decachoron, in 5D the dodecateron, etc.
Now on to your quest about the radii. The circumradius of an $n$-dimensional unit-edged simplex is known to be $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}}$. That of an $n$-dimensional unit-edged mid-truncated simplex ($n$ even) is known to be $\sqrt{\frac n 2}$, and that of an $n$-dimensional unit-edged mid-rectified simplex ($n$ odd) is known to be $\sqrt{\frac{n+1}8}$.
Putting this all together, the $n$-dimensional radius of those intersection kernels - for unit-circumscribed simplices - happens to be $\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}$ for $n$ even and to be $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ for $n$ odd. - Thus indeed $\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$ both for $n=2,\ 3$, as you already calculated.
--- rk

Hi, I totally missed your answer (polytopes were a way of demonstrating a linear algebra result and I ended up finding a simpler, less calculating way). Thanks a lot though !
